# httpClientFactory- services AddHttpClient

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am having a problem following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#basic-usage

this is my configureservices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

this is my page

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

        public IList<Blog> Blog { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {

        }
    }
```

I am receiving following error when browsing to my page:

```html
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication1.Pages.Blogs.IndexModel'.
```

am I missing something?
Thanks for any advice

regards,

foo

Comment: The only potential thing I can suggest checking is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#prerequisites. Do you have those packages installed?

Comment: I am using .net core, and I see the reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Http

Comment: Is it possible to put your solution or at least the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on github?

Comment: It is working now, I was adding it to the wrong startup file........ thanks for you time though : )

Answer (score 7):

the HttpClientFactory is not injected, AddHttpClient injects HttpClient.

try:

```
public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public SampleService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not true, the code snippet you have used is of [Typed Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#typed-clients). Whereas for [Basic Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#basic-usage) and [Named Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#create-client) an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` is injected in the constructor, and its `CreateClient()` method, will return an instance of `HttpClient` for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to create HttpClient:

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

public IndexModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    this.httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## .NET 6.0

As per MSDN:

> `HttpClient` instances created by `IHttpClientFactory` are intended to be short-lived.
>
> - Recycling and recreating `HttpMessageHandler`'s when their lifetime expires is essential for `IHttpClientFactory` to ensure the handlers react to DNS changes. `HttpClient` is tied to a specific handler instance upon its creation, so new `HttpClient` instances should be requested in a timely manner to ensure the client will get the updated handler.
> - Disposing of such `HttpClient` instances created by the factory will not lead to socket exhaustion, as its disposal will not trigger disposal of the `HttpMessageHandler`. `IHttpClientFactory` tracks and disposes of resources used to create `HttpClient` instances, specifically the `HttpMessageHandler` instances, as soon their lifetime expires and there's no `HttpClient` using them anymore.

### 1. Short answer

You need to modify the code in `Index Model` constructor as follows:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public IList<Blog> Blog { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this._httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(); //now use the _httpclient in your class to make HTTP calls.
    }


    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {

    }
}
```

### 2. Long Answer

- To gain detailed knowledge, browse [IHttpClientFactory with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory) at MSDN.
- [Recommended use of `HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use).

You have the following 3 ways:

#### 2.1 Basic Usage

Configure the `HttpClient` in your `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

Using `HttpClient` in `TodoService.cs`:

```
public class TodoService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TodoService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    public async Task GetByIdAsync(Int32 id)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://your.url.com?q={id}");
        //verify and do something with response
    }
}
```

#### 2.2 Named Client

Configure the `HttpClient` in your `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "google",  //for demo only
    client =>
    {
        // Set the base address of the named client.
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");
    });
```

Using `HttpClient` in `TodoService.cs`:

```
public class TodoService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TodoService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    public async Task GetByIdAsync(Int32 id)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { id }), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        //verify and do something with response
    }
}
```

#### 2.3 Typed Client

Configure the `HttpClient` in your `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TodoService>(
    client =>
    {
        // Set the base address of the named client.
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");
    });
```

Using `HttpClient` in `TodoService.cs`:

```
public class TodoService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TodoService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task GetByIdAsync(Int32 id)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { id }), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        //verify and do something with response
    }
}
```

#### 2.4 Generated Clients

[The 4th way as per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#generated-clients).

### 3. `HttpClient` Guidelines:

- [HTTP client guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)
- [Lifetime of `HttpClient` instances generated by `IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#httpclient-lifetime-management)
- [Why one should avoid Typed Clients in singleton services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#avoid-typed-clients-in-singleton-services)